# ifstream' file not found on Mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, compiler-errors, fstream

I'm using a Mac and I'm learning C++. I'm trying to open and read a file and I wrote a few lines code to do it. But when I compile it, either with gcc or g++ or clang, the compiler fails because it can't find the istream file. Is there a way to install or download the default library again. Thank you

Edit:

This is the code:

```
#include <ifstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream ligand("ligand_dataset.txt");

    if( ligand.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File ok";
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open the file";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us your code. What exact file are you trying to include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ifstream header is replaced with fstream

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream f(....);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ifstream is a subclass of istream. It's not the same, and one does not "replace" the other.

Comment: Even if I replace with <fstream> header, I don't resolve the problem

Comment: I don't know why but if I use Xcode it builds the code without any error, but if I compile through terminal it doesn't work